# What is difference between $http.get() vs axios.get() in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js, axios

I have get little bit confused to understand the main difference between `$http.get()` and `axios.get()`.

I have checked out many resources but I did not get any satisfactory answers. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Nothing other than the client making the call. `this.$http` could even be an instance of axios.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter both do the same thing? basically whats the main difference?

Comment: Axios is a popular 3rd party http client. `this.$http` is simply a property that references an instance of an http client. The calls are identical in the end.

Answer (score 2):

The $http is a global variable probably you defined in your vuejs project, please search for $http in your project and you might find it's just the implementation of axios, which will give you an easy access to your axios library with global configuration.

axios is a library which capable of sending and receiving Http requests
check it here [axios library](https://github.com/axios/axios).

so in short answer they are the same

Answer (score 1):

As it can be seen in [source code](https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-axios/blob/2.1.5/src/index.js), the only thing that vue-axios plugin does is providing `$http` property for Vue instance and components that use it.

This is a form of dependency injection and serves two purposes:

- `this.$http` can be accessed inside Vue components instead of carrying `import axios from './my-axios-instance'` everywhere, this is particularly useful in non-modular environments or when base `axios` is refactored to `axios.create()` instance at some point
- Axios instance can be swapped for a hierarchy of Vue components, e.g. configured with different base URL or headers for a feature module