# The difference between axios and this.$axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am developing using nuxt and gridsome.
These are all vue frameworks and I found that there are something interesting.

When I do like this:

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    ...
    created: function created() {
        axios.get(process.env.NUXT_ENV_API_URL + '/users').then(res=>{
        this.options=res.data.map(function(data){
            return {name: data.url, provider_id: data.provider_id};
        });
    }
```

I got 401 error(backend is laravel).

```
message: "Unauthenticated."
```

But when I use this, it's working.

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
...
created: function created() {
    this.$axios.get(process.env.NUXT_ENV_API_URL + '/users').then(res=>{
        this.options=res.data.map(function(data){
            return {name: data.url, provider_id: data.provider_id};
        });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between $http.get() vs axios.get() in vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120119/what-is-difference-between-http-get-vs-axios-get-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 2):

It's because Axios allows to create instances of itself which you can therefore customize. So when you do `axios.get`, underlying, Axios creates an instance on the fly before using it. When you do `this.$axios.get`, you use an already created instance which got customized somewhere else in your code (by adding some HTTP headers for example)